# redirect to previous page

Tags: php, codeigniter

so here i am with "maybe another stupid question"
so  here i want to ask how to redirect to previous page if the case is somehow like this:
i have view:

a. home_view    b. about_view    c. contact_view

then i have login view that (now currently after i login it'll redirect me into the home_view)

I want if i access login_view from about_view then the redirect function will redirect me to about_view, or if i access login_view from contact_view then the redirect function will redirect me to contact_view and so on. How to make redirect function to the previous page(not a single page) ? Maybe some tricks using php? or codeigniter itself?

Comment: i see now, thanks that was great. so i just need to post the url with hidden input. thanks a lot :D

Comment: i highly recommend you to watch the [codeigniter from scratch](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/) videos. it wont take long, i build 3 or 4 websites just by watching them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple when you have login and you go to login_view just set default redirect to about_view or contact_view when had login. 
But if you want to redirect to previous page you have to trick with session must set session ex : `$SESSION['last_view'] = $yourlastview;`. $yourlastview can be set when you in about_view or contact_view or another view and when you go to login_view just check that `$SESSION['last_view']` and redirect to that view.

Regard's

Jefri

Answer (score 0):

You can use query string to solve this problem.
Like when you call login script from about us page access url as **login.php?page=1** where page=1 for aboutus page similarly you can page=2 for contact us page. At login page you can get the redirect page by the query string can redirect to the respective after successfully login using header function.
e.g. `Header('Location:about.php');`

Comment: To list all possible pages is not very good idea... 
+ When you use Framework as CI you should be using its libs and helpers, in this case, for redirecting Wawan should use redirect('pagename') from uri helper.

Comment: if i use redirect('pagename') this only for redirecting to single page, CMIIW. i still yet to figure out what function or logic that will help me in CI framework as i new to this framework.

Answer (score -1):

just use redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'refresh')

Answer (score -1):

This works.

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```

Comment: i will give it -1 for one reason. `$this->agent->referrer()` uses `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` which is inconsistant among browsers and may not be available. As of now, the working solution in cross browsers is to append the url and retrieve it as get variable.

Comment: Actually it's not inconsistent amongst browsers, although some browsers do have the ability to turn it off I feel the chances of someone doing this are slim and the impact on the site is higher with storing an extra variable than one in 10,000 people not being redirected to a their previous page. Considering it's a pretty obscure setting that the vast majority of people don't even know exists I don't feel this deserves the downvote.

Comment: I disagree. When i started using HTTP_REFERER, i found that it is mostly present in chrome, less occurence in firefox, and even less in IE. Having said that, i will agree that in majority cases, **your code will work**. and I would have consider it as good answer **had other better alternatives were not available**. but there is. to append the url. google, facebook and others uses this method. Hence i put it -1 so that when future references are made, this -1 provides a notice that there is some issue regarding using this code which you must consider yourself before using it.